# Rails 2.3.11 Administrator Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, rubygems, administration

This is my first question here in StackOverflow :)

I've been searching for the best **plugin for administrator** for my **Rails 2.3.11** app.
I can create my own but I have to rush my project so I decided to use these kinds of plugin.

I already searched **rails_admin** and **active_admin**. There are both good but I think that's for **Rails 3 only**. So **I need to find some admin plugins for Rails 2.3.11**.

Your ideas are much welcome :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give Typus a try.  It works on rails 2.3 and is quite popular, although the author isn't planning on maintaining the 2.3 version anymore.

https://github.com/typus/typus/wiki/requirements